# prevent window resize behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I have written a css using percentages.
- I want to keep the percentages

How can I prevent the layout changes when browser window re-sizes?

I mean I dont want the percentages to take effect ONLY at browser window resize time.

Comment: wow - confusing - you want them or not?

Comment: Do you understand what you have asked ?

Comment: You will want to post some code to go along with this for us to examine. Also your question doesn't make much sense in that you seem to be asking if you can use percents without percents being percents... You might want to include why you want to do this as well.

Comment: I did not to be verbose while posting. i wanted to use percentages to have responsive design across different screen sizes but on the same screen, if browser window re-sizes I did not want percentages to take effect. any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: people just like to downvote...anyways I think somebody understood below

Comment: How can a question be downvoted twice with an answer which has been upvoted thrice?

Comment: it is a poorly worded and confusing question with no coding examples, screen shots, or other clues to help figure out what you are talking about.  that is why you get downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use percentages, but not have them based on the window, you'll have to wrap them in a fixed-`width` (or, at least, `max-width`) block:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="column-left">
    </div>
    <div id="column-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
}

#column-left {
    width: 30%;
}

#column-right {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Demo: http://cssdesk.com/3gJNj

Comment: thanks. If I set the width of #container in jQuery based on screen size, my layout will be adjusted appropriately right??

Comment: @gauravjain It's likely, but whether it works entirely depends on your layout. Just note that this does, at least in part, defeat the purpose of responsive design -- it isn't just for matching the device, though that is one of the greater benefits; it's for "*responding*" to the viewport in its present state.

Comment: thanks...I have a video player (mediaelement.js)...I was resizing it when browser window size changes....but I did not like it..hence I decided to keep the video player size same irrespective of browser size ON THE SAME SCREEN...thanks again for pointers

Comment: @gauravjain Ah. Sorry. Your question left a bit too much to interpretation, so thought you wanted to "*freeze*" the entire `<body>`. You may still want to let it "shrink-to-fit" for smaller screens, but you can set a `max-width` to prevent it from growing too large: `#video-container { max-width: 500px; width: auto; margin: 0 auto; }`.